# Change Data Capture (CDC)

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, change-data-capture

I was reading this [article](https://rjmetrics.com/resources/guide/data-collection-tools) about ETL for analytics databases, and I came across this interesting note:

> *If you discover that your internal applications are deleting data that’s important for analysis, you have two options: either ask your
>   software engineers to modify the application code to avoid deletions,
>   or **implement a data pipeline that includes Change Data Capture
>   (CDC). CDC preserves the state of a database at every point in its
>   history so that, even if data is deleted from the production schema,
>   it is still available for analysis.** This solution is often far less
>   invasive than re-architecting an application to avoid deletions.*

I'm relatively new to these tools.  If I have a ruby on rails app with typical CRUD actions (on a MySql database), instead of re-writing my code to preserve data:

- Could I actually implement something like RJ metrics so I don't need to modify my code but get to keep all my data?  If not RJ Metrics,
- Are there services out there that allow me to keep a stream of my data so I don't have to re-write code?